Expectation of the number of winners
I have the following problem on Probability.
There are 100 people who participate in a Coin Flip competition. These 100 people are divided into pairs. Each pair (2 person) run a coin flip to determine the winner. Then goes the second round where the original 100 people are divided into pairs again (the pairs can repeat). The winners are those who win the coin flip in both rounds.
Question: what is the expectation of the total number of winners?
Is it just 25 as the sum of probabilities for each person to become a winner? (0.5*0.5 * 100)
Or should we somehow take into account the results of the first round before we start analyzing the results of the second round?
Thanks.

This is a nice question because the intuition is not clear: while it may seem obvious the answer will be $25$, you might have doubts about the pairings in the second round. Some games in the second round will be between two players who both won in the first round; at most one of these will be a "double winner" (so it feels like this reduces the total). Also second round games will be between two players who both lost in the first round; neither of these will be a double winner.
A way to think about this is to count the number of different types of games in the second round.
Let's say there are $G_{LL}$ games between players who both lost in the first round, $G_{WW}$ games between players who both won and $G_{WL}$ between a player who won and one who lost. There are $50$ games in the second round; so $G_{LL}+G_{WL}+G_{WW}=50$.
Say the number of "double winners" is $X$. We have $\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}\left(G_{WW}\right)+\frac12 \mathbb{E}\left(G_{WL}\right)$, because all of the games between winners produce a double winner, and we expect half of those between a winner and a loser to produce one.
But by symmetry, we expect $G_{LL}$ to be the same as $G_{WW}$, so
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\mathbb{E}\left(G_{WW}\right)+\frac12 \mathbb{E}\left(G_{WL}\right)=\frac12 \left[\mathbb{E}\left(G_{WW}\right)+\mathbb{E}\left(G_{LL}\right)+ \mathbb{E}\left(G_{WL}\right)\right]=25$$

it's fun that we both came up with the "double winner" thing. You were faster, though :^)

Only just! I think this question is all about intuition so even similar answers might be useful.

At the end of the first round you have $50$ winners $(W)$ and $50$ losers $(L).$ Now, let's start round two! $50$ pairs are formed. A pair can be of four types $(WW),$ $(WL),$ $(LW)$ and $(LL).$
Since the number of $W$'s and $L$'s is the same, we'll have $\textbf{on average}$, $50/4$ pairs of type $(WW),$ $50/4$ pairs of type $(WL),$ $50/4$ pairs of type $(LW)$ and $50/4$ pairs of type $(LL).$
A match of type $(WW)$ will necessarily bring a double winner.
Now consider a match of type $(WL)$ or $(LW)$. Both $W$ and $L$ have the same probability of winning the second round; thus, $\textbf{on average}$, half of these matches will bring a double winner.
Finally, we are able to say that, $\textbf{on average}$, the number of double winners is
\begin{align}&\mathbb E(\#\{\text{(WW) matches}\}) \\&+ \frac12\mathbb E(\#\{\text{(WL) matches}\}) \\&+ \frac12\mathbb E(\#\{\text{(LW) matches}\})\\&=\frac{50}{4}+\frac12\frac{50}{4}+\frac12\frac{50}{4}\\&=25.\end{align}
